# pdo drivers no value in linux

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have install `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql` and i did `sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql`.

Command `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i pdo`:

[image]

Command `dpkg -l php*mysql`:

[image]

And my pdo in phpinfo():

[image]
I treid uncomment `extension:pdo_mysql` in php.ini without success.

Comment: That's `7.2` in the screenshot. Also note the `CLI`. There are `php.ini` files for `CLI` and another for `Apache`

Comment: I tried uncomment in php.ini in cli and apache2

Comment: @ryan When you change some ini for Apache, you need to reboot it. For Ubuntu: sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: i have restart apache and mysql it does not work

Comment: how did you solved the issue? Facing the same issue. I see pdo_mysql driver is enabled for cli but not for apache-server.

Answer (score 3):

for the same issue on php 8.0

use command sudo apt-get install php-mysql

and restart xampp

[here I got pdo_mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm9A4.png)

Comment: After 2 hours of searching and trying things to get Joomla to upgrade to php 8, this was the answer that somehow no other SO, blog, or doc seemed to mention. (in this case it was apt install php8.0-mysql) I'm actually still using MySQLi rather than PDO, but no matter. Thank you Rohit Sonawane!

Answer (score 0):

I had more than one versions of php installed on my system. In my case my apache was using another version of php. make sure your apache uses the right version of php (you can check current version on top of the phpinfo page).

If you want to change the php version that apache uses, write those lines to the command line.

```
a2dismod php8.1

a2enmod php8.2

systemctl restart apache2
```